# Calculation use key up function with a thousand separator format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sum, keyup

i want to make a calculation when user key in, the result will show in other field. with format number with thousand separator like 2,500.00

so if i sum **2,500.00** + **2,500.00** the result must be 5,000.00

but my code show **4.00**

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  if (key.length == 0) return;
  var regex = /^[0-9.,\b]+$/;
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}

function toFloat(z) {
  var x = document.getElementById(z);
  x.value = parseFloat(x.value).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
}

$( ".fn" ).keyup(function() {
 var nmi = $('#nmi').val();
  var a = $('#a').val();

  var total = parseFloat(nmi) + parseFloat(a);
  $("#total").val(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input onchange="toFloat('nmi')" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required="required" class="form-control fn" placeholder="RM" name="nmi" id="nmi">

<input onchange="toFloat('a')" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required="required" class="form-control fn" placeholder="RM" name="a" id="a">
<br> total
<input onchange="toFloat('total')" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required="required" class="form-control fn" placeholder="RM" name="total" id="total">
```

Comment: `parseFloat(2,500.00)` returns 2 because of the comma `,`. Use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove the comma and then `parseFloat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try this one,,, thats works for me "Dial Gtg"

```js
$('input.CurrencyInput').on('blur', function() {
  const value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '');
  this.value = parseFloat(value).toLocaleString('en-US', {
    style: 'decimal',
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
  });
});

$('input.CurrencyInput2').on('blur', function() {
  const value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '');
  this.value = parseFloat(value).toLocaleString('en-US', {
    style: 'decimal',
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
  });
});


$( ".fn" ).keyup(function() {
 var a = $('#a').val().replace(/,/g,'');
 
  var b = $('#b').val().replace(/,/g,'');

  var total = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
  $("#total_nya").val(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="CurrencyInput fn" id="a">

<input class="CurrencyInput2 fn" id="b">

<input class="total_nya" id="total_nya">
```

Answer (score 0):

When `parseFloat('2,500.00')` will return `2` because of `,`.

> **parseFloat**: parses its argument, and returns a floating point number. If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -), numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, **it returns the value up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding characters**

remove `,` from value by using `replace()`

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  if (key.length == 0) return;
  var regex = /^[0-9.,\b]+$/;
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}

function toFloat(z) {
  var x = document.getElementById(z);
  x.value = parseFloat(x.value).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
}
$( ".fn" ).keyup(function() {
 var nmi = $('#nmi').val().replace(/,/g,'');
 
  var a = $('#a').val().replace(/,/g,'');

  var total = parseFloat(nmi) + parseFloat(a);
  $("#total").val(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input onchange="toFloat('nmi')" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required="required" class="form-control fn" placeholder="RM" name="nmi" id="nmi">

<input onchange="toFloat('a')" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required="required" class="form-control fn" placeholder="RM" name="a" id="a">
<br> total
<input onchange="toFloat('total')" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required="required" class="form-control fn" placeholder="RM" name="total" id="total">
```

Comment: thank u maheer, its works,but i have one more bugs again, if user type 2500 then it will change to 2,500.00 its okay, but the problem is if user type 2,500.00 it will change to 2.00, and if user copy paste 2,500.00  it will change to 2.00 too.please help me

Comment: @rzl21 so what do you want it to be?

Comment: if user type manual  2,500.00  it will not change to 2.00 , i want user can type 2,500.00 or 2500 but will show 2,500.00

Comment: @rzl21 can't figure out any solution sorry

Comment: @rzl21 can't figure out any solution sorry

Answer (score 0):

Simple for your change in code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fn').on('input', function() {
    this.value = this.value.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,2}/);
    calculate();
  });
});

function calculate() {
  var t = 0;
  nmi = ($("#nmi").val() ? parseFloat($("#nmi").val()) : 0);
  a = ($("#a").val() ? parseFloat($("#a").val()) : 0);
  $("#total").val(nmi + a);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="10" required="required" class="form-control fn" placeholder="RM" name="nmi" id="nmi">

<input type="text" maxlength="10" required="required" class="form-control fn" placeholder="RM" name="a" id="a">
<br> total
<input type="text" maxlength="10" required="required" class="form-control fn" placeholder="RM" name="total" id="total">
```